# Rebuild everythyng on any file change in meteor

Tags: meteor

Is there any way to rerun complete rebuild of meteor app when any file is changed? Normally meteor rebuilds only the changed file and all others are chached. So maybe disable cache or any way to force rebuild during meteor is running so I wouldn't have to stop it and run again?

I've read something about caching https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html#caching-build-plugins but I have no idea how to implement something with that.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to trigger a full build every time?

Comment: To resolve all dependencies

Comment: The Meteor build system does that already for you. Personally I haven't had any trouble with the incremental build. The only time it has trouble is when you delete or rename files, but that isn't very often

Comment: No, it does not. Just please answer the question if you know. There is use case behind it where I know I need that.

Comment: Could you explain the use case please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936972/recompile-after-imported-file-changed-in-meteor-app